# Find $\operatorname{Log}(1-i)$ where $\operatorname{Log}z$ is the principal value.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts

My attempt starts with $\log z=\operatorname{Log}|z| + i\operatorname{Arg}z$. I start with the $\operatorname{Arg}$. We know

$$|1-i|=\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{2}\implies\sin\theta=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\implies\theta=\frac{7\pi}{4}=-\frac{\pi}{4}$$

So, we have

$$\operatorname{Log}(1-i)=\log z + i(-\frac{\pi}{4})\implies$$
$$\text{Log}(1-i)=\log z - i\frac{\pi}{4}$$

At this point, I'm confused on how we find the $\log z$ part of our statement. I don't think using the definition of $z=e^{\log z}$ is beneficial -- it seems redundant.

Comment: You need to calculate $\;\log |z|=\log 2\;$, with $\;log=\;$ natural logarithm, also denoted by $\;ln\;$ sometimes. Thus $$Log(1-i)=\log2+\frac{7\pi i}4$$ Yet for the principal value it is more customary to take $\;-\pi<\arg z<\pi\;$ , so in fact $\;\arg(1-i)=-\frac{\pi i}2\;$ instead of $\;\frac{7\pi i}4\;$ .

Comment: How are you getting $\log 2$? I think I have an idea, but $|z|=\sqrt{2}$, so why would we square this?

Comment: @help Is it $\log z=\operatorname{Log}|z|+i\operatorname{Arg}z$ or $\operatorname{Log} z=\log |z|+i\operatorname{Arg}z$ or $\operatorname{Log} z=\log z+i\operatorname{Arg}z$? Each time you write a different expression in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, I would not have posted this, but there seems to be confusion among the comments.

I will assume that if $z = re^{i\theta}$,

with $r \in \Bbb{R^+}$

and $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$ that

$\text{Log}(z) = [\log(r)] + i\theta.$

If $z = (1 - i)$, then $r = \sqrt{2}$ and $\theta = -\pi/4$.

Therefore, $\text{Log}(z) = [\log(\sqrt{2})] + i(-\pi/4).$

Comment: I now see what's going on here. The notation of the textbook is odd, I was looking too literally, and missed the point. The definition given of what Log is - is the relation I first wrote. The capital Z versus the lowercase z really made me think these were two different things.

Comment: @help Not every professional Mathematician is good at writing Math text books.